# problems after upgrade from 1.13.1 to 2.6.2

Tags: wagtail

I've upgraded my site from Django 1.11.10 / Wagtail 1.13.1 to Django 2.2.6 / Wagtail 2.6.2

All seems fine except:
1) I can't add a page under home

[image]

2) Can't move pages, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'allowed_subpage_models'`

Have I missed a setting somewhere?

Full trace for move error:

```
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797605 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026] Internal Server Error: /internal/portal/admin/pages/520/move/
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797660 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797666 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797671 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     response = get_response(request)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797674 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797678 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797682 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797687 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797691 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797695 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797699 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 102, in wrapper
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797713 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797717 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py", line 34, in decorated_view
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797721 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797724 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py", line 739, in move_choose_destination
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797728 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     target.can_choose = page_perms.can_move_to(target)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797732 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 1904, in can_move_to
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797735 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     if not self.page.specific.can_move_to(destination):
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797739 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 996, in can_move_to
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797742 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     return self.can_exist_under(parent)
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797746 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]   File "/var/www/portal_django-upgrade/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 973, in can_exist_under
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797749 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]     return cls in parent.specific_class.allowed_subpage_models()
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797754 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'allowed_subpage_models'
[Thu May 21 12:36:21.797762 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1026]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the "home" page hadn't migrated correctly (at all?). Created a new root page, moved "home" under it. Then was able to move all the sub pages from "home" to the new root.